# LINQ Left Join Causes error in SubSonic.Core

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

I am using the latest version of SubSonic 3 and ActiveRecord.  I am trying to do a left join in LINQ.  It fails with an error somewhere down in SubSonic.

I have a Vehicle object and a VehicleImage object  The Vehicle can have multiple images, but it is not required. so a left join is appropriate.

This is what I have

```
var vehicle = from v in Vehicle.All()
              join dl in DealerLocation.All() on v.DealerLocationID equals dl.ID
              join vi in VehicleImage.All() on v.ID equals vi.VehicleID into VehicleImages
              from vij in VehicleImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
              && vij.IsPrimary
              select new
              {
                  v, vij.Image
              };
```

This is the error I get

```
The expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Project.Data.Vehicle,Project.Data.DealerLocation],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Data.VehicleImage]]]' is not a sequence
```

This is the stack trace

```
   at SubSonic.Linq.Translation.QueryBinder.ConvertToSequence(Expression expr)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Translation.QueryBinder.VisitSequence(Expression source)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Translation.QueryBinder.BindSelectMany(Type resultType, Expression source, LambdaExpression collectionSelector, LambdaExpression resultSelector)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Translation.QueryBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Translation.QueryBinder.Visit(Expression exp)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Translation.QueryBinder.Bind(QueryMapping mapping, Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.QueryMapping.Translate(Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Translate(Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.GetExecutionPlan(Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.QueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a SubSonic bug.  You might want to post this on SubSonic's github's issues page: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues

Answer (score 1):

It seems there still isn't a fix in place for this. A simple fix (dirty one albeit) is to create a view that handles the left join and fills the empty data from the right with default data and have SubSonic do a simple join on that view.

I know it's terrible but its a fix for now. I couldn't see dropping SubSonic due to this limitation. I'm sure it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Trying Fluent Query can be a solution for now maybe. 
Something like:

```
var DB = new myDB();
IList<LiteObject> myLiteObject = DB.Select
    .From<Table1>()
    .InnerJoin<Table2>()
    .LeftOuterJoin<Table3>()
    .Where(Table1.IdColumn).IsEqualTo(1)
    .And(Table2.IdColumn).IsEqualTo(2)
    .ExecuteTypedList<LiteObject>();
```

where LiteObject includes fields from all tables.

Comment: Looks like the Fluent Query can do what I need for now but I am having another issue.  I don't have a good way to get my data from multiple tables into the results of the fluent query list.  I have a number of tables that are joined to where the column names are the same as the other tables.  With LINQ I was aliasing these columns.  Fluent query doesn't seem to have support for that.  So executing typed list will not work as the column names cannot match the names in my class.  Am I missing something in Fluent Query?

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  Fluent Query does not table qualify column names in the FindColumn so you end up getting a lot of the same column back in your query.  That has all kinds of issues.  Guess I am going to create a view.

Comment: i didn't try yet but the docs says (Simple Select with typed columns):

int records = new NorthwindDB.Select(
    new string[] {
      ProductTable.ProductIDColumn, 
      Product.ProductNameColumn })
  .From<Product>().GetRecordCount();